# Failure/Error: response.should render_template(:new) expecting <"new"> but rendering with <"">

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json  
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
  before_filter :admin_only, :except => [:show, :index]

  def new
   @post = Post.new
  end
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'forgery'
require 'populators'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/test/fixtures"

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

**posts_controller_spec.rb**

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe PostsController do
  fixtures :all
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  render_views

  before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
  it "new action should render new template" do
    get :new
    response.should render_template(:new)
  end
end
```

> ruby 1.8.7, rspec 2.11, Rails 3.2.19

I get this error **expecting <"new"> but rendering with <"">** how can I pass this case ... I tried many suggestions but didnt get any success .. Please Help Am stuck with it ... :(

**NOTE: I cant change the code of a controller**

Comment: You do not authorize the user for an action `new`, `before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]`.

Comment: @Зелёный is there any work around for it ?

Comment: It's obviously, make an authorization for the user.

Comment: sorry Am new at this and ok let me try it ..

Comment: Check this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Use the sign_in helper to sign in a fixture `User` record.
user = users(:one)

@request.env['warden'].stub(:authenticate!).and_return(user)
@controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(user)

get :new
assert_template 'new'
```

this works for me using https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs and thanx @Зелёный for the direction :)